Arduino IDE Serial Monitor is working, but not Putty - esp8266
I have an esp8266 that most often won't work with Putty, but always works with Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE.
Baudrate is set to 115200. Putty fills the terminal window with odd characters and the power to the esp8266 seams to disappear when opening a Putty window.
The esp is programmed to wait for commands via serial and write response to serial. I am using the serialEvent() method for this.
I have tried to add Serial.setTimeout(10000), but it did not help.
Any ideas?

make sure that the settings in PuTTY are the same as the serial monitor

The main difference between the PuTTY and the Arduino serial monitor is
that the latter sends one message at a time, with all the characters of
the message immediately following each other, whereas PuTTY sends each
character as soon as you type it. If you want you sketch to be
compatible with both, you have to read the serial port until you find a
proper line terminator. See Reading Serial on the Arduino, by
Majenko.
You should also watch your line terminators. IIRC, PuTTY defaults to
sending CR ('\r') when you hit the return key, and it expects your
sketch to terminate its output lines with CRLF ("\r\n"):

CR moves the cursor horizontally all the way to the left
LF moves the cursor vertically, one line down.

The Arduino Serial.println() method does end the lines with CRLF.
